# File with first bit of every byte set to 0

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I was given a file that seems to be encoded in UTF-8, but every byte that should start with 1 starts with 0.

E.g. in place where one would expect polish letter 'ę', encoded in UTF-8 as `\o304\o231`, there is `\o104\o031`. Or, in binary, there is `01000100:00011001` instead of `11000100:10011001`.

I assume that this was not done on purpose by evil file creator who enjoys my headache, but rather is a result of some erroneous operations performed on a correct UTF-8 file.

The question is: what "reasonable" operations could be the cause? I have no idea how the file was created, probably it was exported by some unknown software, than  could have been compressed, uploaded, copied & pasted, converted to another encoding etc.

I'll be greatful for any idea : )

Comment: Although it's an interesting question, it isn't appropriate for SO because it is fundamentally one of opinion and / or speculation.  FWIW, a decade or two ago I might have suggested that the file could have gone through a 7-bit mail channel, but I would no longer consider such treatment to be in any way reasonable (or likely).

Comment: Might it be UTF-7?

Comment: @TomBlodget this is not UTF-7. The text would look VERY different and less human readable. `ę` is `+ARk-` in UTF-7.  Clearly whatever the UTF-8 file was passed through, it simply chopped off the high bit of each byte.  No *sensible* text encoding would do that.